# how to create a simple class-based react input component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a text input component that has an initial value. The problem is that I can either have an initial value or I can change its value.

Im very beginner so please dont be rude.

This is my code:

```
import * as React from "react";

export class TextBox extends React.Component<{ value: any, onBlur?: Function, isAutoFocus?: boolean }> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: props.value
        }

        /*this.setState({
            value: props.value
        })*/

    }

    public render() {
        return <input /*value={this.props.value}*/ autoFocus onChange={(event) => { console.log("set new value"); this.setState({ value: event.target.value }) }} ></input>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the state instead of props to control the input's value

```
export class TextBox extends React.Component<{ value: any, onBlur?: Function, isAutoFocus?: boolean }> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: props.value // this sets the initial value to what is passed from the props
        }
    }

    public render() {
        return <input value={this.state.value} autoFocus onChange={(event) => {this.setState({ value: event.target.value })}} ></input>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class TextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {    this.setState({value: event.target.value});  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```